# Postgresql return setof record

Tags: postgresql, select, boolean, row, plpgsql

I have a custom type:

```
create type some_type as (
    some_bool_param     boolean, 
    str                 varchar
);
```

I create a table with fields of this type and insert some data:

```
create table test_table (
    strs some_type
);

insert into test_table(strs) values
  ((false, 'First str'))
, ((false, 'Second str '))
, ((false, 'Third str'))
, ((false, 'Yet another str'));
```

And now I try to return setof `some_type` data:

```
create or replace function get_str() returns setof some_type as
$$
declare
    r some_type;
begin
    for r in 
        select * from test_table loop
    return next r;
    end loop;
    return;
end;
```

I call `get_str()`:

```
select * from get_str();
```

But get an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  error in boolean type value: "(f,"First str")"
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "get_str" line 4 at FOR by result of SELECT
> ```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create or replace function get_str() returns setof some_type as
$$
declare
    r some_type;
begin
    for r in 
        select strs from test_table loop
    return next r;
    end loop;
    return;
end;
```

Just in case: declaring a table declares its rowtype as well, so you don't need a separate `CREATE TYPE` here. This would work as well:

```
create table test_table (
    some_bool_param     boolean, 
    str                 varchar
);

insert into test_table values (false, 'First str');
insert into test_table values (false, 'Second str ');
insert into test_table values (false, 'Third str');
insert into test_table values (false, 'Yet another str');

create or replace function get_str()
returns setof test_table as
$$
    SELECT  *
    FROM    test_table;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: The suggested fix for the loop doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a loop with current versions of PostgreSQL any more for that kind of function. Use [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_str()
  RETURNS SETOF test_table AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   TABLE test_table;  -- shorthand for: SELECT * FROM test_table
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or an SQL function like @Quassnoi provided.
Note that this returns a nested composite type (`SETOF test_table`, not `SETOF some_type`).

**Oddly**, this works as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_str5()
  RETURNS SETOF some_type AS
$func$
   TABLE test_table;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The outer row wrapper is silently removed, which is a bit quirky of Postgres to say the least.

#### About the error

Your function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_str()
  RETURNS TABLE (strs some_type) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR strs IN
       SELECT (t.strs).* FROM test_table t
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT r;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the **bold** part. Assignment to a row or record type in a `FOR` loop is done **subfield by subfield**. That's typically convenient, but gets confusing when working with nested composite types.

You have a composite type (`some_type`) inside a table row (`test_table`) - **two** levels of nesting. That's typically not what one would want, but that's what you presented us with.

You need to decompose / unwrap *twice*.

- Your original code only decomposes the outer row wrapper with `select * from test_table`.
- @Quassnoi's suggested fix `select strs from test_table` fails in the same way: strs is decomposed from the table row by direct reference, but `strs` is still a row type that needs to be decomposed itself before assignment.

Answer (score 2):

According to its declaration, the function get_str() is supposed to return a set of record with the `some_type` structure, which is 2 columns with 1 boolean and 1 varchar.

Wile the function actually returns a set of record having 1 column which is typed `some_type`.

Try by replacing `return next r;` with `return next r.strs;`